# No output is shown when I'm executing C++ from java code

Tags: java, c++, terminal, command

There is no output for the code below knowing that it gives output only if there is no input stream in the associated c++ code (code.cpp):

```
        String command = "g++ -o code.bin code.cpp";
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

        p.waitFor();
        System.out.println("exit: " + p.exitValue());
        p.destroy();


        Process p1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("./code.bin < input.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p1.getInputStream()));

        String line = "";
        while((line = br.readLine())!=null){
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        p1.waitFor();
        System.out.println("exit: "+p1.exitValue());
        p1.destroy();
```

for example this code will give an output:

```
    #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int main(){
        cout<<"hello world\n";
        return 0;
    }
```

while this code doesn't:

```
    #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int main(){
       int x;
       cin>>x;
       cout<<x<<endl;
       return 0;
    }
```

I executed the commands in my terminal and it gave the wanted output, so anybody knows the reason behind this?

Answer (score 0):

Late answer. In my similar case, flushing the output buffer with `fflush(stdout)` proves to work.